# How to set different icons for app and for its notifications?

Tags: android, firebase, xamarin, xamarin.forms, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm using a picture with black background and white sign as an icon for my app. The problem is when I'm getting a notification a icon at the top of the display is completely white (I don't know why to be honest, when screen is locked it looks as originally).

I want to solve this problem by setting different icon for notifications, I can use [this site](https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/icons-launcher.html), when I'm using a text icon generated by this site it works just fine.

I'm wondering how to set different icons for my app and its notifications, I know it's possible, but I only have folders that are used for both app and notification icon (drawable-[hdpi/mdpi/xhdpi/xxhdpi/xxxhdpi]).

Comment: I don't quite understand the question. Are you asking how you specify a specific icon for a notification?

Comment: Notification icons should be monochrome. Any color data is stripped leaving only alpha channel intact. If you see it colored on lock screen its probably displaying your app icon and not notification one.

Comment: spartygw
Yes, because now my notification icon is the same as my app icon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved, I added below to AndroidManifest.xml (application section)

```
<meta-data android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon" android:resource="@drawable/new_notification_icon" />
```

Comment: Thanks for your sharing, please accept your answer.

Answer (score 1):

> The problem is when I'm getting a notification a icon at the top of the display is completely white (I don't know why to be honest, when screen is locked it looks as originally).

You set the SetSmallIcon() in the `Notification.Builder`.

To understand the Android documentation which is as follows  – “Update or remove assets that involve color. The system ignores all non-alpha channels in action icons and in the main notification icon. You should assume that these icons will be alpha-only. The system draws notification icons in white and action icons in dark gray.”

you can convert your notification icon to an Android friendly one with a few clicks.

In [Notification icon generator](https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/icons-notification.html#source.type=image&source.space.trim=1&source.space.pad=0&name=ic_stat_myicon), open up your icon file. Convert all parts of the image that you don’t want to show to transparent pixels. All colors and non transparent pixels are displayed in white.

Comment: If above answer is helpful, please accept it as answer(click the “✔” in the upper left corner of this answer), it will help others who have similar issue

Comment: It didn't work, I've added new 36x36 png file to _projectname\projectname.Android\Resources\drawable_ and this is new part of code (MainActivity.cs, OnCreate method):

`new Notification.Builder(this)
                .SetSmallIcon(projectname.Droid.Resource.Drawable.new_notification_icon)
                .Build();`

Notification icon is still the same as app icon.

Comment: I'm using Firebase Cloud Messaging, I don't know if it matters, maybe I have to use this code somewhere else?